# ¿como concatenar objetos de una clase en php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo la clase Mensaje:

```
class Mensaje {

    public $contenido  = "";
    public $destino    = "";
    public $estado     = -1;
    public $message_id = -1;

    function __construct( $destino, $contenido ) {

        $this->contenido = $contenido;
        $this->destino   = $destino;
    }

    function queue( 
        $url, 
        $api_user, 
        $api_pass, 
        $api_version 
    ) {
        $info = array(
            'api_version' => $api_version
            'cmd'         => 'api_queue_sms',
            'content'     => $this->contenido,
            'destination' => $this->destino,
            'password'    => $api_pass,
            'username'    => $api_user,
        );
        $args = urlencode( json_encode( $info ));
        echo $args;

        $res = file_get_contents( $url + '?' + $args ).read();
        $obj = json_decode( $res );

        if ( $obj[ 'success' ] ) {
            $mensajes[ $i ].$estado = 0;
            $this->message_id = $obj[ 'message_id' ];
            echo 'Mensaje insertado exitosamente. Ticket: ' + str( $obj[ 'message_id' ] );

            return 1;

        } else {
            $mensajes[ $i ].$estado = -1;
            echo 'Error al insertar mensaje. Codigo de error: ' + $obj[ 'error_code' ];

            return -1;       
        }
    }


} //class
```

Necesito concatenar los objetos creados de ésta clase. 
Código donde intento concatenar con `append`:

```
/*** Parte donde quiero concatenar ***/
for ( $c=0; $c < $numero; $c++ ) {

    $mensajes->append( new Mensaje( $datos[0], $datos[1] ));
    $mensajes[ $i ]->queue( $url, $api_user, $api_pass, $api_version );
    $i = $i + 1; 
}
```

Error que obtengo:

```
> Call to a member function Mensaje() on null in C:\AppServ\www\test_msj_php.php on line 83
```

Comment: Mira en " $mensajes->append(Mensaje($datos[0], $datos[1]));" debe ser " $mensajes->append(new Mensaje($datos[0], $datos[1]));"; da un vistazo más amplio a como tienes tu código y como se ve en tu planteamiento; parece está incompleto.

Comment: Sería superinteresante saber cual es la línea 83 (la que lanza el error) en el código que aportas.

Answer (score 0):

Al constructor de clase le falta la llave de cierre `}` y sobra una llave al final de la función *`queue,`* por eso no encuentra la clase *`Mensaje`*.